# React Native - zipping a file

Tags: react-native, zip

I'm trying to create a zip archive out of a folder I've placed images and a database, for a backup functionality.
The problem is I cant zip the file so that I can share it. I'm using the package `react-native-zip-archiv` that I have installed using `npm install react-native-zip-archive --save`
What am I doing wrong?

```
    const sourceFile = folderBackup
    const zipFile = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}backup1.zip`;
    await FileSystem.deleteAsync(zipFile)
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(zipFile)
    

    console.log(sourceFile)
    console.log(zipFile)
  
    try {
      await zip(sourceFile, zipFile)
      console.log("File zipped: ", zipFile);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error zipping file:", error)
      console.log(zipFile)
    }
```

The error: "TypeError: cannot read property 'zipFolder' of null"